# Python Version 3 - ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, pandas

Getting the mentioned error when trying to execute this excel comparison script, please help.
Objective of the script is to be able to compare both the excel and highlight the difference, also would be great if you can suggest how can I include columns like Primary Key

````
df1=pd.read_excel('File1.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('File2.xlsx')

df1.equals(df2)

comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
print (comparison_values)

import numpy as np
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

df1.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx',index=False,header=True)


python3 compare_excels.py 
compare_excels.py:8: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare_excels.py", line 12, in <module>
    rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it seems like `df1` and `df2` are both one-dimensional arrays. Hence, the numpy's `where()` function returns a tuple containing one single value, so when you type:

```
rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values==False)
```

You're actually trying to assign an nonexistent second value to `cols`. If you want to assign the returning value to `rows`, you should have something like:

```
rows, = np.where(comparison_values==False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your File1.xlsx and File2.xlsx are not the same sizes, you must reindex df1 with the index of df2 before comparing two df.

```
df1 = df1.reindex(df2.index)
```

Here is a full streamlined code example:

````py
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_excel('File1.xlsx')
df2=pd.read_excel('File2.xlsx')
df1 = df1.reindex(df2.index)
df1.equals(df2)

comparison_values = df1.values == df2.values
print (comparison_values)

import numpy as np
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])

df1.to_excel('./Excel_diff.xlsx',index=False,header=True)```
````